# Run 'app' with coverage in Android Studio 1.2.1.1

Tags: android

In Android Studio 1.2.1.1 there is an option for running the app called "Run 'app' with coverage".
What is different when running the app this way?

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA provides a dedicated action that allows you to perform run with code coverage measurement. The code coverage data are processed according to the option selected in the Coverage page of the Settings dialog box.

To run with code coverage measurement

1. Do one of the following: Open the desired file in the editor, and
   choose Run  with coverage on the context menu. When running
   tests with coverage, note that you can run the entire test class, or
   each individual test method, depending on the caret location. Select
   the desired run/debug configuration, and then on the main menu
   choose Run | Run  with coverage. On
   the main toolbar, click runWithCoverage. This will launch the
   selected run/debug configuration.
2. If the Show options before applying coverage to the editor check box
   has been selected in the Coverage page of the Settings dialog box,
   choose whether you want to replace the active coverage suites, or
   add the collected data to the active suites, or do not want not
   apply coverage data. You can also opt to skip this dialog in the
   future. In case any other option has been selected, the respective
   action will be performed silently.
3. Explore the collected coverage data in the Coverage tool window.

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-with-coverage.html)